# How to toggle content of different ul li?

Tags: jquery, toggle

When I click a `li` in topmenu the `div` of another `ul` block should be displayed.
I have `ul` `li` in Topmenu like this:

```
<ul class="level0" style="width: 925px;">
<li class="level1">
<a href="">Shop By Collection</a> 
</li>
<li class="level1">
<a href="">Shop By feature</a>
</li>
<li class="level1">
<a href="">All category</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

And In another block I have `ul` `li` like this:

```
    <ul class="cat-list-1">
<?php foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
 <li class="category-li-1">
<a href= "<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($cat) ?>" >
  <div class="main-cat-1" ><?php echo $cat->getName() ?> </div>
  </a>
  <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                <div class="sub-cat-1 " style="display:none;">
                    <ul class="subcat-list-1">
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

When I click the anchor tag `a` of `level1` in topmenu, `<div class="sub-cat-1 ">` Should be toggled and displayed.

The jquery which I tried is this:

```
 <script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
  $j('li.level1 a').click(function(e) {
      $j('div.sub-cat-1:visible').hide();
    $j('div.sub-cat-1', this).toggle();
  });

});
</script>
```

But when I click `level 1` the div doesn't `sub-cat-1` open up (ie) the `div` doesn't toggle. Someone please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As long as display is set to none, you can try to force it to become visible what you want, but the browser wouldn't have the slightest clue in what context to render.

you'll want to use "visibility: hidden;" on the sub-cat-1 div instead of "display: none;" and I'd expect it to work fine :)